# ProFTPD not working properly anymore after chmod accident

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, ftp, plesk

**Background**

Yesterday morning I was configuring a WordPress installation on my vserver via `SSH` and screwed up like a proper DAU (been logged in as `root` of course). :(

I wanted to set the `plugins` directory to `755` and forgot the `.` in the path. So I ended up executing `chmod -R 755 /*` instead of `chmod -R 755 ./*`.

When I realized my mistake the script already ran for like 2-3 seconds, before I hammered `Ctrl+C`.

As to be expected, this really messed up my system. However, ***I got most of it fixed*** with a friends help. He fortunately has the same vserver at the same provider.

I "copied" the file permissions from his installation using `find /* -exec stat -c "chmod %a \"%n\"" {} + >~/default_permissions.` and ran the script on my vserver.

**Problem**

Most of the system seems to work again. Plesk, HTTPD, Mail, SSH. But ***the only thing still not working properly is ProFTPD.*** And I can't figure out why. I can't find any relevant log files, besides `usr/local/psa/var/log/ftp_tls.log` and `/usr/local/psa/var/log/xferlog`. But these don't contain any related error messages.

**Symptoms**

When I connect via normal FTP, it closes the connection instantly on connect, without asking for username / password:

```
root@hostname:/# ftp hostname.tld
Connected to hostname.tld.
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection
```

When I connect via sftp, it only works when I login as `root`, but not as normal ftp user.

```
root@hostname:/# sftp -v user@hostname.tld
Connecting to hostname.tld...
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7.1, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to hostname.tld [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'hostname.tld' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@hostname.tld's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 1424, received 1960 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 31175.5, received 42910.0
debug1: Exit status 1
Connection closed
root@hostname:/#
```

I'm almost 100% sure that this is most likely due to some files still having the wrong permissions. But I'm a bit lost here ... Any help would be highly appreciated!

**Edit**

I tried reinstalling ProFTPD as suggest by MariusMatutiae. Unfortunately it didn't work.

```
root@hostname:~# sudo apt-get install --reinstall proftpd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting proftpd-basic instead of proftpd
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcrypt-rijndael-perl psa11-php-fakepackage libcrypt-cbc-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  proftpd-doc proftpd-mod-mysql proftpd-mod-pgsql proftpd-mod-ldap proftpd-mod-odbc proftpd-mod-sqlite
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  proftpd-basic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 90 not upgraded.
Need to get 929kB of archives.
After this operation, 2294kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ lucid-security/universe proftpd-basic 1.3.2c-1ubuntu0.1 [929kB]
Fetched 929kB in 0s (6206kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously deselected package proftpd-basic.
(Reading database ... 99546 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking proftpd-basic (from .../proftpd-basic_1.3.2c-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/proftpd-basic_1.3.2c-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/pam.d/proftpd', which is also in package psa-proftpd 0:1.3.4c-ubuntu10.04.build115130528.15
dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/proftpd-basic_1.3.2c-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I then tried reinstalling psa-proftpd, but it didn't work either.

```
root@hostname:~# sudo apt-get install --reinstall psa-proftpd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of psa-proftpd is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcrypt-rijndael-perl psa11-php-fakepackage libcrypt-cbc-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 90 not upgraded.
```

**Edit 2**

***Problem solved***

I discovered that the `/var/log/daemon.log` file got an entry added everytime I tried a ftp connection:

```
proftpd[17762]: Fatal: ScoreboardFile: : unable to use '/var/run/proftpd_scoreboard': Operation not permitted on line 72 of '/etc/proftpd.conf'
```

After a bit of Google'ing I found this post: https://forums.proftpd.org/smf/index.php?topic=3516.0

This guy had the same problems like me. After changing permissions it stopped working for him.

So I again compared the permissions of the `/var/` and `/var/run/` folders of both servers and changed it on mine according to the other server ... 
And now I'm able to connect to FTP again! WHEE! :D

Comment: Why don't you simply `apt-get install --reinstall` your proftpd package? You can set aside configuration files quite easily, then reinstalling is much simpler than searching for a needle in a haystack.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Yes, you are right. But I'm unsure if this doesn't mess up anything related with Plesk.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Got it solved.